# What if a thread don't call ReleaseMutex once for each time that the mutex satisfied the conditions of a wait function?

Tags: c, windows, mutex

The thread func like the example below.

```
unsigned WINAPI thread(void *arg)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);  
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);//wait for mutex twice
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    return 0;
}
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects)and Windows via C/C++ says that "a thread must call ReleaseMutex once for each time that the mutex satisfied the conditions of a wait function".

When I try wait twice but release once, other thread can still own the mutex successfully(the mutex should have been released incorrectly), why does this happen?

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject` awaits the ownership of the mutex, there's no point in calling it twice before release; the thread releases the lock and the ownership is immediately taken by the other thread

Comment: See [`WAIT_ABANDONED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject).